# Select records without parent with Hibernate using Criteria API

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, orm, annotations

How select records without parent with Hibernate using Criteria API?

Here is my Java code for select with parents

```
getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Category.class).add(
Restrictions.eq("parent", new Category(parentId))).list();
```

Category Java code

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CATEGORY")
public class Category implements NamedModel{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "CATEGORY_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "CATEGORY_RELATIONS",
        joinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "CATEGORY_RELATIONS_CATEGORY_ID", referencedColumnName = "CATEGORY_ID")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "CATEGORY_RELATIONS_PARENT_ID", referencedColumnName = "CATEGORY_ID")})
    private Category parent;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "parent")
    private List<Category> children;//...
}
```

CategoryRelations Java code

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CATEGORY_RELATIONS")
@IdClass(CategoryRelations.CategoryRelationsPrimaryKey.class)
public class CategoryRelations implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "CATEGORY_RELATIONS_CATEGORY_ID")
    private long categoryId;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "CATEGORY_RELATIONS_PARENT_ID")
    private long parentId;

    @Entity
    @IdClass(CategoryRelationsPrimaryKey.class)
    public static class CategoryRelationsPrimaryKey implements Serializable    {
        private long categoryId;
        private long parentId;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Restriction#isNull(propertyName)](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html#isNull(java.lang.String)) function for your requirements.

```
Restrictions.isNull("parent")
```